# Is there a defined name for the execution context that encapsulates all others in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a defined name for the execution context that encapsulates all others in JavaScript?

For example is it called the "global execution context". That phrase is not mentioned in the ES6 spec as far as I can find.

Comment: isn't that `window` on browser and `global` on node?

Comment: I don't think so, no. window and global are objects on the heap referred to by items on the stack. The root execution context sits on the bottom of the stack.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [there is no such](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29884027/1048572) "*execution context that encapsulates all others*" in javascript, and the question is void…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called "the [global environment](https://es5.github.io/#x10.2.3)" as per the ES5 spec (or see the [equivalent section](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-global-environment-records) of the ES6 spec):

> The global environment is a unique Lexical Environment which is created before any ECMAScript code is executed. The global environment’s Environment Record is an object environment record whose binding object is the global object (15.1). The global environment’s outer environment reference is null.

Or perhaps you are looking for the "[initial global execution context](https://es5.github.io/#x10.4.1.1)", whose lexical and variable environment are references to the global environment.

Comment: But a lexical environment is only one component of an execution context. It is an aggregate relationship.

Comment: I was looking for the initial global execution context. I believe the global environment to be different. I am specifically asking about execution contexts.

Comment: Notice there is no single "initial global execution context". That section name is confusing, it should better read "initialisation of a global execution context", for these steps are executed whenever global code is entered.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any term more specific than simply "global environment" or "global environment record" (to draw a distinction with its binding object) which is used several places in the ES6 pecification such as [§8.1](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-lexical-environments) and [§8.1.14](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-global-environment-records) (draft spec, those section numbers may drift).