# Is the global Execution Context pushed onto Execution Context Stack(ECS) before Execution Context of a Job is initialized?

Tags: javascript, browser

I have read these:

- [Is the initial global execution context ever popped off the call stack in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879525/is-the-initial-global-execution-context-ever-popped-off-the-call-stack-in-javasc)
- [Is it possible for Global Execution Context to pop off the execution stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869145/is-it-possible-for-global-execution-context-to-pop-off-the-execution-stack)

But I still confused about it.

When the stack if empty, a Job will be executed.It will create a Execution Context for the Job.

So the question is, will the Execution Context of the Job be put at the bottom of the stack or firstly create a global Execution Context and put  the Execution Context of the Job onto it?

Comment: the latter, as suggested by the term `stack`, it's always `LIFO` (Last In First Out)

Comment: @Isaac I need something to convince me. LIFO does not mean it will firstly create a global Execution Context.

Comment: Then I'm afraid have to flag it as a duplicate by the link you shared above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879525/is-the-initial-global-execution-context-ever-popped-off-the-call-stack-in-javasc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the initial global execution context ever popped off the call stack in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879525/is-the-initial-global-execution-context-ever-popped-off-the-call-stack-in-javasc)

Comment: The link shared is about if the global execution context ever popped off, the answer is YES.
My question is if the global execution context is recreated when a Job is executed.

Comment: @Isaac In other way, when a Job is executed, how many Execution context in stack? just its own? or with global?